# Is INSERT INTO...SELECT... a row-by-row-insert operation OR a bulk transaction operation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im dealing with some **HADR_SYNC_COMMIT** waits on my current MSSQL 2016 AG cluster when executing a stored procedure which inserts data into a table (tableA) using another table (tableB) using the `INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * from tableB` syntax.

This SP gets executed multiple times a minute and inserts a fair amount of records in tableA by an external application. The requirement by the application developers is to be able to execute this more often, sequentially.

I have tried changing the avail. mode of the cluster to Asynchronous commit and the SP flies. Execution is instantaneous and everyone is happy. However due to multiple reasons, the avail. mode MUST remain in Synchronous commit (see notes below)

Notes:

- Availability mode MUST be in sync commit mode.
- There is no disk latency in the SECONDARY replica
- There are no network issues between the 2 servers

Given the above, i would like to minimize the footprint of the SP in the transaction log.

1. Is the above syntax a row-by-row operation?
2. If so, how can i modify this to hit the transaction log less? (and in essence minimize the **HADR_SYNC_COMMIT** wait?)
3. Is there anything else i am missing, that can help out?

Comment: *"Is the above syntax a row-by-row operation?"* It's a set-based operation, it is not row-by-row. A row-by-row process would `INSERT` each row individually; so if you had 1,000 rows, there would be 1,000 `INSERT` statements.

Comment: To me, it would make sense to create an insert trigger in table B and insert a record into A there. Also, if you are inserting a lot of records, you are going to have a lot of hits to the transaction log. Just the nature of the beast. This may be the case where smaller transactions may help (i.e. selecting part of records from table B and not all)

Comment: The fact that you see a notable difference between sync and async modes indicates there is considerable latency [somewhere] for the transaction to be committed on the secondary replica. Have you experimented with *delayed durability*?

Comment: @Vasya Note that triggers fire once per _statement_, not per _row_. If the operation on `tableB` does an `insert` of 1,000 rows then the trigger will fire once and `inserted` in the trigger will contain 1,000 rows. The trigger could still process the rows in smaller batches, but that isn't the kind of activity one wants in a trigger.